# Slider in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to implement a slider in `shiny`.
On my `server.R` side I have this

```
output$daterange <- renderUI({
    if( (input$var1 == 6) ) {
        sliderInput(inputId = "daterange",
                label = "Datum",
                min = as.Date("2019-01-01"),
                max = as.Date("2001-01-01"),
                value = as.Date("2001-01-01"),
                timeFormat = "%b %Y"
    )        

    } else {
        sliderInput(inputId = "daterange",
                label = "Datum",
                min = as.Date("1990-01-01"),
                max = as.Date("2000-01-01"),
                value = as.Date("1990-01-01"),
                timeFormat = "%b %Y"
        )        

    }
})
```

On my `ui.R` side I have this:

```
uiOutput("daterange")
```

What I get in the App is not a slider, but a field where I can type in text...

[image]

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Please provide ui.R and server.R code, so we can reproduce the problem. See `shiny::shinyApp(ui = ..., server = ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Got it.
Apparently `jQuery` does not play well with `shiny` 
When I add this

```
tags$body(tags$script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"))
```

I get the behaviour (at least in my set up).